# Библиотека поиска картинки в картинке win 10 с вызовом из 1с

Tags: 1с

Нужно искать подкартинку в картинке. Считаем что обе картинки лежат в папке. Основная система -1с. Но 1с делать подобное не умеет. Подскажите можно ли вызвать готовую функцию из какой - то библиотеки windows?

Answer (score 0):

В 1С способ вызова выглядит следующим образом:

```
    // VBA Аналог будет выглядеть так см https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/createobject-function
    // Set EXCELApplication = CreateObject("EXCEL.Application"); 
// -------------- Код 1С --------------
    EXCELApplication = Новый COMОбъект("EXCEL.Application"); 
    // Делаем всё что нам нужно
    EXCELApplication.Application.Quit();
    EXCELApplication = Неопределено;
```

Ты можешь написать функционал на языке типа VB, C и т.п. с использованием CreateObject() и затем перенести код в 1С с небольшими изменениями в форматировании кода.

Comment: Про com объекты я в курсе. Как их из 1с вызывать тоже. Интересует имя библиотеки умеющей искать картинку в картинке с оберткой под com.